# Log4j does not show line logging when use via .jar file

Tags: java, ant, jar, log4j

I have a program that uses a jar file which uses log4j. 
It's log4j property contains this pattern:

```
[%-5p] (%d) %l : %m%n
```

and when my program accesses a method inside the jar that executes a log, it produces this:

```
[INFO ] (2011-02-25 14:13:43,426) org.fractor.service.AppConfigService.getStringValueOf(?:?) : processing.user: root
```

I tried to include the original src folder of the jar file and when I ran the program again it outputs this:

```
[INFO ] (2011-02-25 14:13:43,426) org.fractor.service.AppConfigService.getStringValueOf(AppConfigService.java:125) : processing.user: root
```

This seems ok but when creating a jar file of the program which contains the jar that uses log4j, it doesn't include the jar's src folder and therefore gives out error.

Is it because it's just referencing the jar's src folder? Do I need to include the jar's src folder in the jar? Seems like using the jar would be useless at this point.

Is there another way for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the jar file contains classes which has been compiled without debug information.

As you've found this is highly desirable.  I would suggest filing a bug with those responsible for building the jar, and then rebuild it yourself if you can.  If not, then include the src folder, but the correct jar is better.

Comment: +1 The tradition in Java is to always compile with debugging symbols turned on (e.g. javac -g).  In June 2010 I analyzed every jar file inside the Maven2 central repository (including jars inside jars!), and over 95% of the classes I looked at had debugging symbols turned on.  Like Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen said, get whoever made the jar to turn on debugging!  (e.g. <javac debug='on'> in build.xml).

Comment: @Julius, the more experienced I get, the more I appreciate that the Java designers understood by heart how important a debugging tool a stack trace is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the Java classes with debug enabled. In ant this would look as follows:

```
<javac destdir="XXXX" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true" encoding="UTF-8">
```

Using javac directly you need to specify the **-g**. See [javac docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Comment: the logging location being slow is an old remark in the documentation which is because the information is derived from throwing an exception and analyzing its stack trace.  That operation used to be much slower than it is today.